# Flex DataGrid not wanted DataTip appears

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, tooltip, flex4.6

Attached you will find a small project to show the issue, there is a screenshow as well in the zip.
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/screenhunter50jan140842.jpg/

Uploaded with [URL=http://imageshack.us]ImageShack.us[/URL]
 - When you constantly refresh **dataProvider** of a **datagrid/advanceddatagrid** unwanted datatips are shown. 
 - In the screenshot you can see the mouse cursor on the first column of the advanced data grid. And a tooltip is show. 
 - In the code the `showDataTips="false"` for the first column.
 - Same is on the regular data grid. ( Though sometimes the **tooltip** is just flickering )
 - No issue with the MX one.

Link to the demo project: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5516677/Datatip%20issue.7z

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. This is exactly the flex's bug. When the dataProvider of DataGrid is changed, renderers are replaced by others from cache, but tooltip remains from previous renderer, which is invisible now.
I propose a workaround. I've just overrided toolTip setter for renderer to check its visibility.

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="secoind" left="300" top="20" width="200" height="200" dataProvider="{dta}" showDataTips="false">
        <mx:groupedColumns >
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup >
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="name" headerText="Name" showDataTips="false">
                    <mx:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <mx:AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
                                <fx:Script>
                                    <![CDATA[
                                        override public function set toolTip(value:String):void
                                        {
                                            super.toolTip = visible ? value : null;
                                        }
                                    ]]>
                                </fx:Script>
                            </mx:AdvancedDataGridItemRenderer>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </mx:itemRenderer>
                </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="text" headerText="Text" showDataTips="true"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
        </mx:groupedColumns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```